# In CentOS, when using Simple Control Panel, how do you access a newly created domain? via IP

Tags: dns, centos

In CentOS, when using Simple Control Panel, how do you access a newly created domain? via IP

edit:  I actually meant to say, where / which file holds the domains / aliases for those domains set up in SCP? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to find out that SCP creates a virtual name CONF file in the httpd directory.  This is where you'll need to go to modify that name.  Under: Turbo*conf

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing to do (assuming by "new" you mean, not yet setup in DNS) is to change your local /etc/hosts file to point to the IP address by the domain name in question.  This works in Windows or Linux or Mac OSX just fine

Comment: Hmm, this might be a bit different.  I actually meant to say, where / which file holds the domains / aliases for those domains set up in SCP?  Thanks!